# Change text inside li with image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I want to change the text inside a li. But this li has got an img. 
Here the html:

```
<div>
<ul>
<li><b><img src="../../../Images/folder1/image1.png">Text1</b><i>0</i></li>
<li><b><img src="../../../Images/folder1/image2.png">Text2</b><i>1</i></li>
<li><b><img src="../../../Images/folder1/image3.png">Text3</b><i>2</i></li>
<li><b><img src="../../../Images/folder1/image4.png">Text4</b><i>3</i></li>
<li><b><img src="../../../Images/folder1/image5.png">Text5</b><i>4</i></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I am trying this:

```
$("li").each(function () {
$(this).text(sometext);
})
```

But it is replacing all, including the img. 
I only want to change the text: Text1,Text2,...

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What text do you want to replace? The `Text1` or the `0`? With what?

Comment: there are 2 text content which one you want to replace and with what

Comment: `<img>` inside `<b>` seem like invalid HTML markup

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Z9f46/1/

Comment: in the $(this).html('<image>text') .. you could try this as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get to the textnodes within an element you need to use `contents()` and then `filter()` by nodeType. You can then use `replaceWith()` to change the text. Try this:

```
$('li:first b').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).replaceWith('foo');
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3NuW/)

I obviously hard-coded this to use the first `li` element, but you can change the selector as needed.

Comment: It is the most elegant way, but I want to use the element to change the text and it is giving me error:

`$('li:first b').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).replaceWith($(this).text() + "hello");`

Comment: `$(this).text()` in the replaceWith of your example is not in scope. You need to use a handler function: `replaceWith(function() { return $(this).text() + ' foo'; });` http://jsfiddle.net/Q3NuW/2/

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/YNLXQ/

```
$("li b").each(function () {
   this.childNodes[1].textContent = "32323";
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the image in a separate variable and after replacing the text prepend the image back.

```
$("li b").each(function () {
    var $img = $(this).find('img'); 
    $(this).text(sometext).prepend($img);
})
```